# Easier way to create and maintain many layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

I have got an application that is essentially a giant calculator.  Within this application it has a total of 75 unique equations and each one has different number of variables and displayed results.  I currently have a sliding drawer implemented with the list of the equations of them to choose from and when they click on it, I have a fragment area to put the screen for calculating it.  I am currently just implementing a fragment activity for each calculation along with a layout for each one.  Does anyone know what best practice is for accomplishing something with this many screens? Do I accomplish them by creating the layout on the fly in the activity? Do I keep it how it is? I am just trying to figure out if the tedious work I am doing with this can be accomplished in an easier manner (I know I have to create the activities to do the work) .

**EDIT**

The layouts vary in complexity depending on the calcuation.  Some of them are to the nth entry from the user and requires a gridview while others will just be simple like example below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android=blah blah
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
   android:background="DCDCDC"
   android:orientation="horizontal" >

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/etTempInput"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_margin="10dp"
       android:layout_below="@+id/tvTempInputLabel"
       android:ems="10"
       android:inputType="numberSigned" >
       <requestFocus />
   </EditText>

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tvTempInputLabel"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:text="Medium_Text"
       android:textAppearance="?androd:attr/textAppearanceMedium" >
   </TextView>

   <Spinner
       android:id="@+id/spinner1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/etTempInput"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/etTempInput"  />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tvTempResult"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/etTempInput"
       android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
       android:text="Medium_Text"
       android:textAppearance="?androd:attr/textAppearanceMedium" >
   </TextView>

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/btnTempCalc"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/tvTempResult"
       android:text="Calculate" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I came to with this is to just create each page by itself as there is no consistency between the pages.  I looked at several options but none of them met my needs. So look out 75 layouts and code files here I come.

Answer (score 0):

really hard without seeing the layouts, but it sounds as building up the layouts dynamically ( perhaps from building-blocks in xml ) could tidy things up

Comment: I have included an example of probably the simpliest layout I have, many of them get advanced.  All of them currently are using relative layouts.

Comment: one is not really helping to see if there is a common baseline through them which could be used to simplify things

Comment: I cannot post many of them as they are large. Some take 2 values from the user, others take 3 values from the user, some take 4,5,6,n number of values from the user. If there was a common theme between them I would use that but I have not been able to find a pattern.